# Facebook API friendslist empty

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In the graph explorer:

`https://graph.facebook.com/12345?metadata=1`

Result:

```
{
  "id": "12345", 
  "name": "list_name", 
  "list_type": "user_created", 
  "metadata": {
    "connections": {
      "members": "https://graph.facebook.com/12345/members"
    }, 
    "type": "friendlist"
  }
}
```

but when I try `https://graph.facebook.com/12345/members`, I get

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

even though I know there are people on that list. The same thing happens with every list.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the apropriate permission?

I guess you need `read_friendlists` permission for this one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/friendlist/members

Comment: Did you check them with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-basic-info?

Answer (score 0):

regarding to the changelog of v 2.0 you can only see friends which are also using the app (if you have requeste the friendlist permissions scope):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

solutions:
a) use the old api version 1.0 till 30th April 2015
b) check out the taggable friends:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends